# How to inherit MenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, menustrip

I have a problem with inheriting a MenuStrip from a Parent class to a Child class. The problem is that in the child class I tried to edit the inherited MenuStrip but I can't do it and in the properties everything is disabled as if the modifier was in private.

In the properties of the MenuStrip of the parent class its modifier is in public and the event associated to that control is in virtual.

```c#
namespace LogicaDelJuego
{
    public partial class TableroPrincipal : Form
    {
        public virtual void nuevoJuegoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DatosPersonales data = new DatosPersonales();
                data.Show();
                data.enviarDatos += new DatosPersonales.EnviarDatosEventHandler(ConfiguracionInicial);
                Inicializador();
                HabilitarBotones(true);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And in the daughter class are the two methods in override.

```c#
using System;
using LogicaJUego;
namespace SocketServidor
{
    public partial class TableroServidor : TableroPrincipal
    {
        SetupServer setup;
        public TableroServidor()
        {
            setup = new SetupServer();
            setup.Show();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void nuevoJuegoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.nuevoJuegoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
        }

        public override void partidaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.partidaToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

But I still can't edit my MenuStrip within the daughter class, I can't even make it expand. In addition, the buttons are associated with these events.

This is the image of the menu in the parent class:

[image]

Comment: Can please you share a more complete example of your class declarations? it looks like your issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: The inheritance is not the problem, the issue is with the designer.  The designers that were added in .NET 2.0 do not support "visual inheritance".  No decent workaround for that, you can only write code in the form constructor to add any menu items.  Mostly cut+paste when you add them first to the base form menu.  And you need to change the Modifiers property of the menustrip from Private to Protected.

Comment: @Sirmyself yes, I can